# Mutual Auth between API gateway and API microservice?

Tags: api, security, authentication, authorization, jwt

I'm writing an API gateway which will expose a single point of entry to various other APIs which can only be accessed via this API gateway.

This API gateway will be serve requests from various frontends such as a website, a mobile app, a desktop app, whatever...

I want to be able to verify that requests to my API Gateway have come from one of these sources and haven't just come from anyone doing a Curl request. To this end I've been looking for a way to authorise these requests. I've looked at implementing JWTs to verify where these requests have come from, with this frontend services would have to share a secret with the API gateway so they could create tokens to send which the API gateway could then verify. I guess the problem comes in the fact that these secrets would have to be securely stored in the frontend apps.

I was wondering if there was a better way of verifying that requests have come from where I expect them to come from?

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to go is to implement an Identity Provider (Single Sign-On / SSO) that implements OpenId Connect or OAuth2. Those protocols have different authentication flows that adapt to a variety of scenarios, included the one you are referring to. You could use the flow `client_credentials` for scenarios where you can make sure the `client_secret` can remain confidential, or you could use the flow `implicit` for browser, javascript applications, where there's no way to keep a secret confidential.
Depending on the scenario your application and front-ends are going to work, you should configure your clients accordingly. Then your microservices will only need to validate the tokens received against the Identity Provider in one of the ways supported by these protocols. OpenId Connect offers an "introspection endpoint" on the implementation, where you can send the token so the Identity Provider validates it on its own.

Keep in mind that JWT isn't actually a protocol, but a format (a standard one, but just a format). On many Identity Providers (IdP) you can choose to emit either a JWT token or a Reference token. The latter is just a GUID that doesn't contain any data, but serves as a reference for the information stored internally on the IdP at the time the token was generated. Then the IdP can provide the data related to that Reference token to the app consuming the token.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can make your own algorithm that generates a unique time dependent access token. The algorithm should be implemented on both the API gateway and the frontends.

The benefit of using JSON web tokens is that JWT is a popular authentication protocol. Open source libraries for most popular programming languages are provided so you dont have to write your own code. Using a standard authentication library will also make it easier for third party apps to access your API.